# gsoap++ linking error

Tags: linux, gsoap

I wrote a soap-client with gsoap++ library. once i compiled this one as a stand-alone test app it was compiled fine, but when i try to compile these classes including in my project i get a lot of linking errors:

```
../common/UserGausClient/UserGausClient.o: In function `GAUS::SSLInit()':
/home/milo/src/pinmoney/src/registrator/../common/UserGausClient/UserGausClient.h:11: undefined reference to `soap_ssl_init'
../common/UserGausClient/soapC.o: In function `soap_faultdetail':
/home/milo/src/pinmoney/src/registrator/../common/UserGausClient/soapC.cpp:117: undefined reference to `soap_malloc'
../common/UserGausClient/soapC.o: In function `soap_getelement':
/home/milo/src/pinmoney/src/registrator/../common/UserGausClient/soapC.cpp:152: undefined reference to `soap_peek_element'
/home/milo/src/pinmoney/src/registrator/../common/UserGausClient/soapC.cpp:154: undefined reference to `soap_lookup_type'
/home/milo/src/pinmoney/src/registrator/../common/UserGausClient/soapC.cpp:155: undefined reference to `soap_lookup_type'
/home/milo/src/pinmoney/src/registrator/../common/UserGausClient/soapC.cpp:215: undefined reference to `soap_match_tag'
/home/milo/src/pinmoney/src/registrator/../common/UserGausClient/soapC.cpp:219: undefined reference to `soap_match_tag'
/home/milo/src/pinmoney/src/registrator/../common/UserGausClient/soapC.cpp:223: undefined reference to `soap_match_tag'
/home/milo/src/pinmoney/src/registrator/../common/UserGausClient/soapC.cpp:227: undefined reference to `soap_match_tag'
/home/milo/src/pinmoney/src/registrator/../common/UserGausClient/soapC.cpp:231: undefined reference to `soap_match_tag'
../common/UserGausClient/soapC.o:/home/milo/src/pinmoney/src/registrator/../common/UserGausClient/soapC.cpp:235: more undefined references to `soap_match_tag' follow
../common/UserGausClient/soapC.o: In function `soap_ignore_element(soap*)':
/home/milo/src/pinmoney/src/registrator/../common/UserGausClient/soapC.cpp:333: undefined reference to `soap_peek_element'
/home/milo/src/pinmoney/src/registrator/../common/UserGausClient/soapC.cpp:337: undefined reference to `soap_match_tag'
/home/milo/src/pinmoney/src/registrator/../common/UserGausClient/soapC.cpp:354: undefined reference to `soap_element_end_in'
../common/UserGausClient/soapC.o: In function `soap_class_id_enter(soap*, char const*, void*, int, unsigned int, char const*, char const*)':
```

and so on. In Codeblocks it linking fined... Here is my Makefile:

```
CC=g++
RM=rm
CFLAGS=-c -g -Wall -DWITH_OPENSSL
LDFLAGS=-lpcrecpp -lpq -lcryptopp -lprotobuf -lrt -lgsoapssl++ -lssl -lcrypto -L/usr/lib/ -L/usr/local/lib/ -lgsoap

SOURCES=../common/PgConnectionManager.cpp \
    ../common/RSADecryptor.cpp \
    ../common/RSAEncryptor.cpp \
    ../common/RSAKeyGenerator.cpp \
    ../common/RSAKeyLoaderBase.cpp \
    ../common/RSAManager.cpp \
    ../common/TcpServer.cpp \
    ../common/UserGausClient/UserGausClient.cpp \
    ../common/UserGausClient/soapC.cpp \
    ../common/UserGausClient/soapuserBindingProxy.cpp \
    ../proto/BalanceHistory.pb.cc \
    ../proto/Bio.pb.cc \
    ../proto/ClientRegistration.pb.cc \
    ../proto/EmployeePermissions.pb.cc \
    ../proto/OperatorAuthentication.pb.cc \
    ../proto/Passport.pb.cc \
    ../proto/Ping.pb.cc \
    ../proto/SearchForBill.pb.cc \
    ../proto/UpdateClientData.pb.cc \
    RequestDispatcher.cpp \
    SQLStorage.cpp \
    SessionManager.cpp \
    main.cpp \


OBJECTS_SEARCHER=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
OBJECTS=$(OBJECTS_SEARCHER:.cc=.o)

SEARCHER=registrator
INCLUDE=-I ../ 

all: $(SEARCHER) 

$(SEARCHER): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@
clean:
    $(RM) -f $(OBJECTS)

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) $< -o $@
```

I linked against all necessary libraries (`-lgsoapssl++ -lssl -lcrypto`) and I checked out requesting functions in these ones:

```
$ nm /usr/lib/libgsoapssl++.a | grep soap_begin_count
00018da0 T soap_begin_count
```

and there are in libraries. so, what a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have to compile one of gSoap's stdsoap2.* files in your make.  The generated soapC file depends on the core gSoap code.

Comment: Nice thought, but `locate stdsoap*` didn't find anything... :(

Comment: It comes with gSoap.  I don't see a path to gSoap in your make.

Comment: You don't need stdsoap2 is you link to the gsoap library as you are doing in your example: The code is compiled and linked with soapcalcProxy.cpp, soapC.cpp, and stdsoap2.cpp (or use libgsoap++.a).

Comment: my test application uses this classes links fine. what's difference?

Comment: I copied /usr/include/gsoap/stdsoap2.cpp and everything works fine! thank you! but only question - how could it be the symbols in object file couldn't resolve when library is present?

Comment: There are a variety of reasons this could happen.  Decompress the static library and make sure the object files have the methods?  Maybe the methods are in a different namespace?  It is hard to tell without the code and build artifacts.

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason for this is the order that the libraries are specified to the linker, **some** linkers require that the libarary containing the definition of a function appears after the object or library that requires it. Try re-arranging the library definitions so that this is the case here and check your linkers documentaion to see if it requires this.

Answer (score 1):

'stdsoap2.cpp' needs to be from the gsoap source directory.

PATH_TO_GSOAP_BUILD/gsoap-2.8/gsoap/stdsoap2.cpp (assuming gsoap-2.8)

Comment: i've found it already, thanks. this file must be the part of project to link it successfully.

Comment: Some doubts regarding the above solution, Where do we need to copy stdsoap2.cpp file?